# URL with query string not matching react-router route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Given this React router configuration:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/farm/:type?period=:period" component={Farm} />
    <Route path="/pen/:penId" component={Pen} />
    <Route path="/pen/:penId/cow/:cowId" component={Cow} />
    <Route path="*" component={Farm} />
</Router>
```

Why is `http://localhost:8080/farm/average?period=day` only matching the catch-all route and not the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query string parameters don't need to be included in the `<Route>` definition.

Changing the route definition to `<Route path="/farm/:type" component={Farm} />`
solved the problem.

Query string parameters are still available under `props.location.query`