# React-router not matching query string

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

My routes are defined as follows:

```
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={App}>
     <Route path="experiments">
       <IndexRoute component={Experiments} />
     </Route>
     <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
   </Route>
 </Router>
```

When I visit `/experiments`, things work as expected and the Experiments component is rendered. However, when I manually enter a URL with query parameters, example: `/experiments?offset=50`, the route doesn't match!

But when I navigate using `<Link to={{ pathname='/experiments', query={offset:50} }} />`, things work as expected. The Experiments component is rendered and `this.props.location.query.offset` is set to `50`.

How do I get the Route to match when a URL with query string is entered manually (or copy-pasted)?

It seems route should match automatically [url-with-query-‌​string-not-matching-‌​react-router-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728059/url-with-query-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bstring-not-matching-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Breact-router-route), but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

**Edit:**
I narrowed down the problem to the *catch-all route* `path="*"`. When I remove this route, everything works (e.g. when I visit `/experiments?offset=50`). But no routes are matched when the catch-all Route is present, even though it is at the bottom of the precedence list.

Comment: Please go back in and edit your post rather than adding on new information in a comment.  Refer to: [Ask] and please show a [MCVE] next time.  You also didn't even bother to complete the 2-minute site tour before asking.

Comment: Apologies. I edited my post to add the new info.

Comment: Excellent.  I just up-voted you for doing that.  One day maybe you'll be editing new user questions and telling them the same, or similar things.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but the match didn't work when it came from a Redirect. The error was on the redirect usage. I've posted my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68852335/6928599. Just mentioning because the problem here was really similar to what I was having, so it can help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of `historyApiFallback` with `history={browserHistory}` to load your route when you manually enter it.

what `historyApiFallback` does, is make it so your server returns `index.html` for whatever URL you try to access and since your routes are then configured with respect to `index.html` so you can access any of the route url directly

In you webpack add

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true;
}
```

Comment: I'm using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and I believe that it uses `historyApiFallback` already.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out this was an entirely unrelated issue. I was using [redux-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/redux-auth) which was causing a redirect to the wrong URL pathname. This was happening after the react-router did its parsing and route matching. Once I fixed that, route matching worked perfectly. I was able to parse the query string from a URL like `/experiments?offset=50` using the Route config in my question above.